# Vector graphics export of Graphics to PDF

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

There seems to be a regression in V13.0 in `Export[]` to `"PDF"`. `Graphics` are rasterized and `"AllowRasterization" -> False` has no effect.  I've searched the site but not found this question.  I did find examples which show vector graphics output, but now, when I try them, they are rasterized.

Is there a way to get vector graphics in a PDF?

```
Graphics@Line@{{0, 0}, {2, 1}};
Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.pdf"}], %, 
  "AllowRasterization" -> False];
First@Import[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm on a Mac M1 Max. If it makes a difference, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I think the PDF does consist of vector graphics. The change appears to be in Import. Use `Import[%, "PageGraphics"]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Carl  I remember that now...I'll search for it on site, but I didn't find it before.  Maybe it should be an answer, though?

Comment: @CarlWoll How do like that? I even answered the duplicate. :) Well, maybe it will be easier to find next time.